# Ethereum Transaction Using cUrl and web3.php, I get a Receipt but the Transaction is not sent to the Network

Tags: php, curl, ethereum

This has been doing my head in all day, after wading through and managing to get all my values converted to hex I create and sign the ethereum transaction using the web3p/ethereum-tx library from GitHub. I put in the cUrl request with the parameters to the infura mainet. I get a response with a transaction hash but when I search for it on etherscan and others it does not show up, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
use Web3\Web3;
use Web3p\EthereumTx\Transaction;

  $balance = bcdiv($balanceInWei, "1000000000000000000", 18);
  $gasTotal = 4000000000 * 21004;
  $value = bcsub($balanceInWei, $gasTotal);
  $gas = dechex(21004);
  $gasPrice = dechex(4000000000);

  function bcdechex($dec) {
    $hex = '';
  do {    
    $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
    $hex = dechex($last).$hex;
    $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
  } while($dec>0);
    return $hex;
  }

  $hexValue = bcdechex($value);
  $nonce = time();
  $hexNonce = dechex($nonce);

  echo $wallet_address;
    // with chainId
    $transaction = new Transaction([
        'nonce' => '0x'.$hexNonce,
        'from' => $wallet_address,
        'to' => '0xMyWalletAddress',
        'gas' => '0x'.$gas,
        'gasPrice' => '0x'.$gasPrice,
        'value' => '0x'.$hexValue,
        'chainId' => 1,
        'data' => '0x0'
    ]);
    $signedTransaction = $transaction->sign($databaseContainer->private_key);

    $url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MyApiKey";
    $data = array(
            "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
            "method" => "eth_sendRawTransaction",
            "params" => array("0x".$signedTransaction),
            "id" => 1
    );
    $json_encoded_data = json_encode($data);

    var_dump($json_encoded_data);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_encoded_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_encoded_data))
    );

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    dd($result);
```

dd is just me dumping the result in larvel. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using hex-encoded current time for the transaction nonce?

Comment: I thought the nonce can be any value as long as it's larger than the value of the previous transaction. Is this not the case?

Comment: The account nonce will start at 0x0 and should be incremented by 1 each time. You can use `web3.eth.getTransactionCount()` to receive the appropriate nonce if you're  not keeping track of it yourself elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried fiddling with the nonce and it seems to be working.

Comment: That's good news! I've posted the answer below, please mark as an accepted answer so that others with a similar problem are able to receive the appropriate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the hex-encoded current time as the transaction nonce. This is not not the correct expected nonce; you need to make sure you're using the correct expected account nonce. You can get this nonce value by calling [`eth_getTransactionCount`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactioncount).

Also note, that you're receiving a transaction hash, not a receipt. The transaction hash is an indicator that your transaction has been sent to the network. A transaction receipt is an indicator of your transaction being successfully mined/validated.